# Can/how would I use .klc files in VS Code?

Tags: msklc

I made a .klc file, but I'm not sure how to set it up with VS Code. Is there a way to add it, maybe in the settings.json? I couldn't find anything saying how to, but I also couldn't find anything saying it wasn't possible.